Caching API call data
I'm using Ktor to call API in my android app in kotlin and now I want to cache the response so that I can use app even if it is offline, how to do that ??
I have used HttpCache but that didn't work
install (HttpCache) {
    val cacheFile = Files.createDirectories(
        Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "ktor_cache")
    ).toFile()
    publicStorage(FileStorage(cacheFile))
}


The Ktor's HttpCache plugin follows the HTTP Caching specification (https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9111.html), so the caching behavior depends on how the server responds to the clients.

In your case,

I want to cache the response so that I can use the app even if it is offline

You need to implement a local database to save data on the user's device. and this is possible using the Room Database.
This is how it works:
When Online

You fetch the data from the server
show it to the user & update the local database

When Offline

Show data from the local database

Please check MVVM News App (retrofit) with local db
